# Why is this MVC method not running in parallel manner?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

**Background**

I have an MVC 5 application and wanted to test if the requests were running in parallel. To do so I used the code below, and opened multiple pages all making the same request.

**Code**

Below is a relatively simple method where I wanted to the parallel nature.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string returnUrl, string message = "")
{
    var rng = new Random();

    var wait = rng.Next(3, 10);

    var threadGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    DebugHelper.WriteToDebugLog($"Thread {threadGuid} about to wait {wait} seconds");
    await Task.Delay(wait * 1000);
    DebugHelper.WriteToDebugLog($"Thread {threadGuid} finished");

    return View();
}
```

The class `DebugHelper` is just used so that I can write to a file safely.

```
public static class DebugHelper
{
    private static readonly object WriteLock = new object();

    public static void WriteToDebugLog(string message, string path = "C:\\Temp\\Log.txt")
    {
        lock (WriteLock)
        {
            File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[] { "", GetDateString(), message });
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

I'm consistently getting this type of output which suggests the threads are blocking each other.

```
2020-03-24T13:43:43.1431913Z
Thread 6e42a6c5-d3cb-4541-b8aa-34b290952973 about to wait 7 seconds

2020-03-24T13:43:50.1564077Z
Thread 6e42a6c5-d3cb-4541-b8aa-34b290952973 finished

2020-03-24T13:43:50.1853278Z
Thread 90923f55-befd-4224-bdd8-b67f787839fc about to wait 4 seconds

2020-03-24T13:43:54.1943271Z
Thread 90923f55-befd-4224-bdd8-b67f787839fc finished

2020-03-24T13:43:54.2312257Z
Thread fa2d8d30-b762-4262-b188-0b34da5f4f04 about to wait 3 seconds

2020-03-24T13:43:57.2370556Z
Thread fa2d8d30-b762-4262-b188-0b34da5f4f04 finished

2020-03-24T13:43:57.2679690Z
Thread 37311a0e-d19e-4563-b92a-5e5e3def379a about to wait 8 seconds

2020-03-24T13:44:05.2812367Z
Thread 37311a0e-d19e-4563-b92a-5e5e3def379a finished
```

**Question**

Why is this occurring?

I was under the impression that any ASP.NET application was multithreaded to begin with, so even in a situation where I don't have the `async/await` setup, I thought it would run these threads simultaneously.

**Update**

As suggested in the answers/comments, my methodology was wrong. After using the following code I could see quite clearly in the logs that it was indeed running in parallel.

```
var targetTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
while(DateTime.UtcNow < targetTime)
{
    DebugHelper.WriteToDebugLog($"Thread {threadGuid} with ID {threadId} doing stuff");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the name of the variable `threadGuid`, are you sure that your code is running in the same thread after the line `await Task.Delay`? You can test it be logging the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` too.

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel with logging - you'll likely get it wrong, as you've done here with your WriteLock. Check out great libraries like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](https://serilog.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It simply boils down to the fact that your debug logging with its `WriteLock` and synchronous  `File.AppendAllLines` forces a synchronization lock onto all asynchronous functions that call it.

You would do far better to have an asynchronous write to debug process that would allow your tasks to continue running.

Product/consumer patter, semaphores, events, use of asynchronous file access APIs all spring to mind.

Comment: There channel API released relatively recently is an awesome way to build out producer/consumer workloads. It's simple, and performs well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using session at all it can lock the user to a single thread. Check for controller level, page level, or filter/attribute session use. If you are unsure try adding

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

to the controller.

Also, await by default will continue on the same thread that began the await. Try using configureAwait(false) to allow it to be flexible in the threads it uses.

```
await Task.Delay(wait * 1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: You should not use .ConfigureAwait(false) in an ASP.NET app. See [guidance on its usage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

Comment: I am *very* well aware of the guidelines. I have been working with Tasks since they released, and have written massive complex multithreaded async applications. They are simply state that because most developers don't understand context very well and tend to forget what thread they need to be on. It *ISN'T* harmful if you don't need the thread context.